# Missing Initial Key Frame Issue in VLC media player

Tags: c++, gstreamer, h.264, vlc, libvlc

I am creating h264 video with this pipeline.

```
udpsrc port={PORT} buffer-size=100000000 ! queue ! tsdemux parse-private-sections=TRUE ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! x264enc key-int-max=20 ! capsfilter caps=video/x-h264,profile=(string)high-4:2:2 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host={DVR_IP} port={DVR_PORT} sync=FALSE
```

But result video missing initial keyframe. Thus when I open the video file with VLC player, nothing happens on the screen until the first key frame.

[image]
Usually, it encounters the first key frame within the first 10 seconds and the video starts playing. Then I can rewind and watch the first 10 seconds too.

With ffprobe, I examined the location and time between key frames.

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=print_section=0 5-1601984964095.ts

3610.187967
3620.185489
3630.193133
3640.187944
3650.185311
3660.182822
3670.188500
3680.184133
3690.185078
3700.182911
3710.183367
3720.182778
3730.184022
3740.184567
3750.182689
3760.185767
3770.184700
3780.190100
3790.189033
3800.184422
3810.195578
3820.184767
3830.189644
3840.191533
3850.200800
3860.189211
3870.186956
3880.182989
3890.187878
3900.180167
3910.179522
3920.181411
3930.182022
3940.186422
3950.185778
3960.189856
3970.192444
3980.182833
3990.182367
4000.181000
4010.184000
4020.183622
4030.184178
4040.186367
4050.180144
4060.177833
4070.194067
4080.197444
4090.197700
4100.178944
4110.185444
4120.180544
4130.186956
4140.184967
4150.188178
4160.202444
4170.193300
```

**My failed solution:**

I updated the pipeline by adding key-int-max = 20 to the x264encoder.

```
udpsrc port={PORT} buffer-size=100000000 ! queue ! tsdemux parse-private-sections=TRUE ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! x264enc key-int-max=20 ! capsfilter caps=video/x-h264,profile=(string)high-4:2:2 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host={DVR_IP} port={DVR_PORT} sync=FALSE
```

Now, because there is one key frame every second, the video continues to play after showing a blank screen for only 1 second. But  file size is doubled due to the frequent use of key frames. So this solution is unsustainable for me.

**My question** is How can I fix this problem? I must watch this video from very beginning! Can I add initial (missing one) key frame to the beginning of the video by somehow updating the gstreamer pipeline?

Or is there a setting in Vlc player to play video up to the first key frame? I tampered with all the settings of VLC but could not find anything usefull.